# Connectivity Maps: A way to implement this efficiently with LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation, mindmaps

I am interested in creating connectivity maps.  While there are a wide variety of ways to handle this, I am particularly interested in a LaTeX-based method for handling this.  Below is an example of a map that I would be interested in creating:

[image: Example connectivity map]

Here we see nodes connected by lines.  The nodes contain text and the lines may be customized by where they intersect a node, text along the line, curves, etc.

I know TIKZ can handle these types of things but I am interested in an efficient method for generating maps via some simple scripting.  The thing I don't know is if TIKZ or some other package can automatically generate node locations to efficiently use the dimensions given to the map.  I am not very interested in mapping these things out by hand.  I would like something that generates node locations based on the connectivity of the nodes as well as something that can automatically draw lines around nodes instead of crossing them.

For instance, given a list of items (each one a node) and a list of connectivity data, is there a way for LaTeX to auto-generate a map?

Comment: If you're not already aware, check out the graphviz gallery (http://graphviz.org/Gallery.php).  It's not LaTeX, but it can output vector graphics.

Comment: Latest version of tikz can do that kind of things with the help of graphdrawing library (requires lualatex to compile because the hard computations for automatically placing nodes and edges are made by lua)